# JavaScript switch/case breaks selecting text inside text input *in Safari for Mac*

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have an input element:

```
<input id="animal" onkeyup="autocomplete()">
```

For a personal project, I want to autocomplete text fields to save time. I use some crude JavaScript like so:

```
function autocomplete() {
  animal = document.getElementById("animal").value;

  switch(animal) {
    case "alli": animal = "alligator"; break;
    case "hipp": animal = "hippopotamus"; break;
    case "ost": animal = "ostrich";
  }
  document.getElementById("animal").value = animal;
}
```

This works fine for my purposes except if I change my mind, I cannot find a way to select the text to delete it. **Backspacing won't get the job done and Cmd/Ctrl+A only selects the text for an instant.**

Interestingly, this problem does NOT occur with this less attractive code:

```
function autocomplete() {
  animal = document.getElementById("animal").value;

  if (animal == "alli") {
    animal = "alligator";
  }
  if (animal == "hipp") {
    animal = "hippopotamus";
  }
  if (animal == "ost") {
    animal = "ostrich";
  }
  document.getElementById("animal").value = animal;
}
```

Would appreciate insight of any kind.

**Edit: This problem only seems to affect Safari. Chrome and Firefox (on Mac) each do not exhibit this problem.**

Comment: Your JS is useless without HTML. When is the function called?

Comment: On onkeyup for the active field. That info is tucked into the first sentence. The html is also super-simple: <input id="animal" onkeyup="autocomplete()">

Answer (score 0):

it might be becasue you dont'have a default case in you switch
try:

```js
  switch(animal) {
    case "alli": animal = "alligator"; break;
    case "hipp": animal = "hippopotamus"; break;
    case "ost": animal = "ostrich";
    default:
     animal = animal
  }
  document.getElementById("animal").value = animal;
}
```

Comment: No, that isn't it